# Trying to show loading wheel from picture box issue

Tags: c#, email, picturebox

I am having an issue trying to display a picturebox with a spinning wheel gif while sending an email through the program.

When the **send** button is clicked nothing happens until the message box shows up saying whether the email was sent or not. If it have the wheel spinning all the time, even when I click the send button it pauses.

My question is how do I get the gif to show during that **processing** time and then hide after it's completed. I have tried running the email send process as a background process, but I still haven't figured it out.

I've been using the basic:

```
PictureBox LoadingWheel = new PictureBox();
LoadingWheel.ImageLocation = @"\\xxxx\xxx\xx";
PictureBox.Visible = True;
PictureBox.Visible = False;
```

Any Ideas?

Also I am trying to figure this out as well:
I have a text box that when I enter the text and hit enter I want it to click the button (I have that part figured out) but I also want it to highlight the button:
[image]

Like this...
[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lj2xV.png)

Answer (score 0):

PictureBox.Visible = True; 
After this line of code call the method which sends the mail then later write PictureBox.Visible = false;

Comment: I have tried putting that before calling the send message method and it still doesn't show up. I have added the code for reference -- disregard the red underline -- I have removed the picture box until I can try some other ideas.

Comment: PictureBox LoadingWheel = new PictureBox();
LoadingWheel.ImageLocation = @"\\xxxx\xxx\xx";
PictureBox.Visible = True;Sendmailfunction();PictureBox.Visible = false;